# How to set the google maps app foremost while driving

Tags: applications, maps, driving-mode

I have been using google maps for a while now as my driving guidance/maps app. It does have one slight inconvenient, while you are driving you'll get all notifications to still crop up space on your screen, and for some apps they might even get in the way of your maps.

Is there a way to keep google maps, or any other maps app for that matter, foremost on my screen?

If I set the phone in driving mode, can I stop other apps from getting screen space/time all at once or is it in a per app basis?

Comment: You may need to use an app / Automation to disable notifications from appearing. [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) -Trigger : app Launched > maps Action > clear notification > all or select apps. This should work. Not tested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[Android Auto](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.projection.gearhead)**.

This will reduce the accessing time for Maps or Any other application required while driving.
 Also During driving and using android auto, you'll have a better experience of Map as the notifications from other apps won't bother you as they do on running the Maps app directly.
Reason for this is to minimize the interruption of other apps while driving.
Android auto is designed with keeping these points in mind and to make driving safer.

Answer (score 2):

For me (Android 6 on a Sony phone), "[screen pinning](http://www.androidguys.com/2015/11/30/how-to-use-screen-pinning-in-android-6-0-marshmallow/)" does this, with no need for third party apps.

The option for me is in "Settings", "Security", "Screen pinning", which you set to "on". You pin an app by swiping up on it from the overview list, then clicking the "pin" icon which will appear. To unpin a pinned app, press and hold the "back" and "overview" buttons at the same time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simple thing you can do is to snooze all your notifications before you start driving. This way you will not receive any notifications while you are using the Maps app and there will not be any interruptions and you can access all your notifications once your travel is over. Alternately, you can download offline maps in Google and switch off your internet completely. This way you will not only receive any notifications, but your battery will also be saved if you are travelling for a long time.